# Why can't Artillery and Anti-aircraft units capture enemy cities?

Tags: panzer-general

The usual drill: your units attack enemy units. Hexagonal field becomes free and you enter the city.

However it does not work when the unit entering city tile is of type Artillery or Anti-aircraft.

Is there any reason for that?

Comment: To clarify, this question is about the original 1994 Panzer General game, right?

Comment: YES, that one :) Original 1994 as well as http://panzergeneraldownload.com/ - PGForever Panzer General remake for Windows XP

Answer (score 3):

This is an abstraction of the problem of urban warfare in real war. Cities will usually have pockets of resistance, even if it's surrounded. Unless everyone surrenders (and, on second thought, even if they did), you would be plain dumb as a general to not make sure that the buildings are clear of enemy resistance. This requires proper ground infantry or armor. You should not assume that the city is just "free for the taking."

Answer (score 2):

Probably because those kinds of units can't really "occupy" a city.  To take control of a city, ground units capable of directly engaging other ground units are usually necessary.  I haven't played Panzer General myself, but even in games like Civilization, you need infantry or armor to take over a city.